# What is the oxidation state of the element Oxygen in the molecule FONS, assuming that it does indeed exist

Tags: everyday-chemistry, oxidation-state

What is the process to determining charges regardless of the molecule? Is there some sort of rule book?

Comment: Look at the bonds, then at the electronegativities. There is nothing as complicated as to justify writing a whole book on the subject.

Comment: After ranking them based on electronegativity values from lowest to highest;  S, N, O, F, what do I do? I don't understand how any one of these will have a positive charge. @IvanNeretin

Comment: Basic concepts are better learned on the examples of _existing_ compounds. Think of sulfuric or nitric acids. What are the formal charges of S and N in them?

Comment: S has +6 and N has +5? @IvanNeretin

Comment: That's right. Now what's strange about them having positive oxidation states? Nothing.

Comment: How are the atoms bonded together?

Comment: @gsurfer04 Its a hypothetical molecule.

Comment: Are you aware of constitutional isomers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Since this is a homework question, I will not give a complete answer to this question (Site Policy).

I will assume that the molecule is:

[image]

Although the molecule is highly strained, lets assume it exists.

Use the simplified formula to find Oxidation number:

$$\text{Oxidation Number}=(\text{Num. of bonds formed with electronegative atoms})-(\text{Num. of bonds formed with electropositive atoms})$$

I'm sure you can continue from here.

Comment: How did you come up with this equation?

Comment: Well, its the only one that satisfies all their valencies :) @XHyper

Comment: How did you create the lewis dot structure in the first place? I'm still struggling with that.

Comment: @XHyper Nitrogen forms 3 bonds, Oxygen and Sulfur each 2, and Fluorine forms 1. Try any other structure, this is the only one.

Comment: Thus, Oxygen would have (1) - (1) = 0 oxidization charge? @Pritt Balagopal